# Unsatisfied Dependency Exception in Delphi XE2

Tags: delphi, unit-testing, dependency-injection, spring4d

I have the following interface:

```
unit uICodec;

interface
uses UITypes,uTPLb_CryptographicLibrary ;

type
  ICodec = interface
    ['{B1858F24-5B76-4468-8BD5-55684EA43CCD}']
    procedure EncryptString(const Plaintext: string; var CipherText_Base64:
      ansistring);
    procedure DecryptString(var Plaintext: string; const CipherText_Base64:
      ansistring);
    function RCGL:TCryptographicLibrary;
    procedure WCGL(const c:TCryptographicLibrary);
    property CryptoLibrary:TCryptographicLibrary read RCGL write WCGL;
    function RSCI:string;
    procedure WSCI(const c:string);
    property StreamCipherId:string read RSCI write WSCI;
    function RBCI:string;
    procedure WBCI(const c:string);
    property BlockCipherId:string read RBCI write WBCI;
    function RCMI:string;
    procedure WCMI(const c:string);
    property ChainModeId:string read RCMI write WCMI;
    function RPWD:string;
    procedure WPWD(const c:string);
    property Password:string read RPWD write WPWD;
  end;
```

with its relevant mock class where the function/procedures don't do anything:

```
unit uMockTPWDDBManager;

interface

uses classes,uTPLb_CryptographicLibrary,uICodec,UITypes;

type

  TMockCodec1 = class(TInterfacedObject,ICodec)
//    constructor Create (Aowner: TComponent);
    procedure EncryptString(const Plaintext: string; var CipherText_Base64:
      ansistring);
    procedure DecryptString(var Plaintext: string; const CipherText_Base64:
      ansistring);
  private
    function RCGL:TCryptographicLibrary;
    procedure WCGL(const c:TCryptographicLibrary);
    function RSCI:string;
    procedure WSCI(const c:string);
    function RBCI:string;
    procedure WBCI(const c:string);
    function RCMI:string;
    procedure WCMI(const c:string);
    function RPWD:string;
    procedure WPWD(const c:string);
  end;
....
function TMockCodec1.RBCI: string;
begin

end;
...
initialization
  GlobalContainer.RegisterComponent<TMockCodec1>.Implements<ICodec>;
end.
```

When I try to run the test with the following code, I have the error

```
procedure TestTPWDDBManager.SetUp;
begin

GlobalContainer.Build;
  FCodec1:=ServiceLocator.GetService<ICodec>;//EUnsatisfiedDependencyException with message 'Unsatisfied dependency  for the service "ICodec"
```

I double checked and all the procedure/functions in ICodec are the same as the ones in TMockCodec1.

Where am I wrong ?

**[UPDATE]**

I followed David's suggestion and, I think, I have found the bug. My .dpr  was the following:

```
uses   DUnitTestRunner,   
uMockTPWDDBManager in 'uMockTPWDDBManager.pas',   
uTCodec1 in '..\uTCodec1;.pas';
```

unit uMockTPWDDBManager has the following initialization:

```
...
initialization
  GlobalContainer.RegisterComponent<TCodec1>.Implements<ICodec>;
end.
```

and unit uTCodec1 have the following initialization:

```
initialization
  GlobalContainer.RegisterComponent<TMockCodec1>.Implements<ICodec>;
```

When I removed uTCodec1 from the .dpr the error message disappeared.

I think that two initializations for the same interface cannot coexist in the same .dpr.

Am I correct ?

**[SSCCE]**

Unfortunately I was able to reduce the unit number down to 3 only.

The following is the .dpr

```
program TPWDDBManager;
{

  Delphi DUnit Test Project
  -------------------------
  This project contains the DUnit test framework and the GUI/Console test runners.
  Add "CONSOLE_TESTRUNNER" to the conditional defines entry in the project options
  to use the console test runner.  Otherwise the GUI test runner will be used by
  default.

}

{$IFDEF CONSOLE_TESTRUNNER}
{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}
{$ENDIF}

uses
  DUnitTestRunner,
  TestuTPWDDBManager in 'TestuTPWDDBManager.pas',
  uTPWDDBManager in '..\uTPWDDBManager.pas';

{$R *.RES}

begin
  DUnitTestRunner.RunRegisteredTests;
end.
```

This is the first unit:

```
unit uTPWDDBManager;

interface

uses IniFiles,uICodec,UITypes;

type
  ICodec = interface
['{B1858F24-5B76-4468-8BD5-55684EA43CCD}']
    procedure EncryptString(const Plaintext: string; var CipherText_Base64:
      ansistring);
    procedure DecryptString(var Plaintext: string; const CipherText_Base64:
      ansistring);
end;

  IInsertPassword = interface
    ['{B197F2EE-8C65-4E59-897F-F69E6E8D252F}']
    function ShowModal: Integer;
    function GetOldPWD : String;
    function GetNewPWD : String;
  end;

  IMessageDlg = interface
    ['{5A527174-50D4-4BB9-8E9F-6A9926B2893C}']
    function MessageDlg(const Msg: string; DlgType: TMsgDlgType; Buttons:
      TMsgDlgButtons;HelpCtx: Longint): Integer;
  end;

  IPWDDBManager = interface
    ['{51C993FE-D96A-4419-AB80-00D65E16C6F8}']
    function GetDBPWD (const Key : string; var Reset : Boolean): string;
    function ChangePWD (OldKey, NewKey : string): string;
    procedure Reset;
  end;

  TPWDDBManager=class(TIniFile,IPWDDBManager)
  private
    FRefCount: Integer;
  protected
  function QueryInterface(const IID: TGUID; out Obj): Integer; stdcall;
    function _AddRef: Integer; stdcall;
    function _Release: Integer; stdcall;
  public
    constructor Create(const FileName: string; Fcodec: ICodec ;
      meggagedlg: IMessageDlg);virtual;
    function GetDBPWD (const Key: string; var Reset: Boolean): string;
    function ChangePWD (OldKey, NewKey : string): string;
    procedure Reset;
    property RefCount: Integer read FRefCount;
  end;

implementation

uses Dialogs, SysUtils,Spring.container;

{ TPWDDBManager }

function TPWDDBManager.ChangePWD (OldKey, NewKey : string): string;
begin
end;

constructor TPWDDBManager.Create(const FileName: string; Fcodec: ICodec ;
  meggagedlg: IMessageDlg);
begin
end;

function TPWDDBManager.GetDBPWD (const Key : string; var Reset : Boolean): string;
begin
  result:='';
end;

function TPWDDBManager.QueryInterface(const IID: TGUID; out Obj): Integer;
const
  E_NOINTERFACE = $80004002;
begin
  if GetInterface(IID, Obj) then
    Result := 0
  else
    Result := E_NOINTERFACE;
end;

procedure TPWDDBManager.Reset;
begin
end;

function TPWDDBManager._AddRef: Integer;
begin
end;

function TPWDDBManager._Release: Integer;
begin
end;

end.
```

and this is the second:

```
    unit TestuTPWDDBManager;
    {

      Delphi DUnit Test Case
      ----------------------
      This unit contains a skeleton test case class generated by the Test Case Wizard.
      Modify the generated code to correctly setup and call the methods from the unit
      being tested.

    }

        interface

        uses TestFramework,IniFiles,classes,UITypes,uTPWDDBManager;

        type

      tcodec1=class(tcodec)

      end;


          TMockCodec1 = class(TInterfacedObject,ICodec)
            procedure EncryptString(const Plaintext: string; var CipherText_Base64:
              ansistring);
            procedure DecryptString(var Plaintext: string; const CipherText_Base64:
              ansistring);
          end;

          TMockInsertPassword1 = class(TInterfacedObject,IInsertPassword )
            constructor create (Aowner: TComponent);
            function ShowModal: Integer;
            function GetOldPWD : String;
            function GetNewPWD : String;
          end;

          TMockMessagedlg = class(TInterfacedObject,IMessageDlg)
            function MessageDlg(const Msg: string; DlgType: TMsgDlgType; Buttons:
              TMsgDlgButtons;HelpCtx: Longint): Integer;
          end;

          // Test methods for class TPWDDBManager

          TestTPWDDBManager = class(TTestCase)
          strict private
            FCodec1: ICodec;
            FPWDDBManager: IPWDDBManager;
            Inifile:TInifile;
            mockmessagedlg:IMessageDlg;
            ReturnValue: string;
          public
            procedure SetUp; override;
            procedure TearDown; override;
          published
            procedure TestGetPWD;
          end;

        implementation

        uses SysUtils,Spring.container,Spring.Services;

        procedure TestTPWDDBManager.SetUp;
        begin
          GlobalContainer.Build;
          FCodec1:=ServiceLocator.GetService<ICodec>;
          mockmessagedlg:=ServiceLocator.GetService<IMessageDlg>;
          FPWDDBManager :=TPWDDBManager.Create(ChangeFileExt((ParamStr(0)),'.ini'),
            FCodec1,mockmessagedlg);
        end;

        procedure TestTPWDDBManager.TearDown;
        begin
          Inifile.Free;
        end;

        procedure TestTPWDDBManager.TestGetPWD;
        var
          reset: boolean;
        begin
        //// this instruction deletes a .ini file ///
          DeleteFile(ChangeFileExt((ParamStr(0)),'.ini'));
          ReturnValue := FPWDDBManager.GetDBPWD('a',reset);
          CheckEqualsString(ReturnValue,'');
          // TODO: Validate method results
        end;

        procedure TMockCodec1.DecryptString(var Plaintext: string;
          const CipherText_Base64: ansistring);
        begin
        Plaintext:=StringReplace(string(CipherText_Base64),'encripted','decripted',[
          rfReplaceAll,rfIgnoreCase]);
        end;

        procedure TMockCodec1.EncryptString(const Plaintext: string;
          var CipherText_Base64: ansistring);
        begin
          CipherText_Base64:=ansistring(StringReplace(Plaintext,'decripted','encripted',[
            rfReplaceAll,rfIgnoreCase]));
        end;

        { TMockInsertPassword1 }

        constructor TMockInsertPassword1.create(Aowner: TComponent);
        begin
        end;

        function TMockInsertPassword1.GetNewPWD: String;
        begin
          result:='new pwd decripted';
        end;

        function TMockInsertPassword1.GetOldPWD: String;
        begin
          result:='old pwd encripted';
        end;

        function TMockInsertPassword1.ShowModal: Integer;
        begin
          result:=1;
        end;

        { TMockMessagedlg }

        function TMockMessagedlg.MessageDlg(const Msg: string; DlgType: TMsgDlgType;
          Buttons: TMsgDlgButtons; HelpCtx: Integer): Integer;
        begin
          result:=-1;
          if Msg='File ' +
            'E:\Delphi\Projects\Components\Tests\TPWDDBManager\TestFolder\Win32\Debug\.ini doesn''t exists' then
            result:=1
          else if Msg='File ' +
          'E:\Delphi\Projects\Components\Tests\TPWDDBManager\TestFolder\Win32\Debug\.ini doesn''t exists' then
            result:=2
        end;

        initialization
          // Register any test cases with the test runner
          RegisterTest(TestTPWDDBManager.Suite);
          GlobalContainer.RegisterComponent<TMockCodec1>.Implements<ICodec>;
          GlobalContainer.RegisterComponent<tcodec1>.Implements<ICodec>;
GlobalContainer.RegisterComponent<TMockInsertPassword1>.Implements<IInsertPassword>;
          GlobalContainer.RegisterComponent<TMockMessagedlg>.Implements<IMessageDlg>;
        end.
```

I can compile the source but when I run the test I have the error message EUnsatisfiedDependencyException with message 'Unsatisfied dependency  for the service "ICodec"

If I remove the class tcodec1 and remove `GlobalContainer.RegisterComponent<tcodec1>.Implements<ICodec>;` 
then no more error messages.

Is it because you cannot register multiple classes in the same project and referring to the same interface ?

Comment: Not intimately familiar with how Delphi does mocking, but you have several more methods listed in the interface declaration than what you show in the mock.

Comment: Have you included the unit uMockTPWDDBManager explicitly in the uses clause of the unit where TestTPWDDBManager is located?

Comment: Also, GLobalContainer.Build only needs to be called once, so you could (should? not sure), move it to the .dpr file - I usually place it after the Initialize method call

Comment: No, @500, there are 12 methods in both the interface and the class. Properties don't have to be repeated because they're just syntactic sugar. The class can repeat them if it wants, but it won't affect the interface. The class can even declare the properties differently than how they appear in the interface.

Comment: @Jason yes, uMockTPWDDBManager  is included in the uses clause. The application compiles regularly. I have the error message when I start the test run. I also moved around the GLobalContainer.Build in different places but the error is still the same.

Comment: Could you put together a simplified example? Remove all the crypo units and that. Ideally we could have a single .dpr file with all that's need to create the error.

Comment: You still have not got an SSCCE. I won't look at this until there is one.

Comment: @RobKennedy: Indeed. Missed that point. My excuse is that the OP uses a somewhat unconventional naming schemes for getters/setters.

Comment: I didn't know there is a convention for naming patterns for getters/setters. Sorry.

Comment: You are most likely not using the latest version from the trunk but an older one (I guess the zip one from the download section)

Answer (score 0):

If you have multiple registrations for the same service type you should register these using a distinct name. Otherwise the container cannot decide which one to return if you call Resolve/GetService.

Another advice I would like to give for unit tests: don't use the container there but manually wire up your needed dependencies (i.e. mocks). In your example it does not even make sense because you are not letting the container construct your system under test (so it could inject any dependencies you are mocking).

If you use the latest version from the trunk you should not get an error anymore when registering more than one unnamed service. However it will return the last registered component for the service (or the last one you called .AsDefault on). This will be changed most likely so my first advice still stands (using named registrations if you have multiple).

Comment: Is the latest version available at the following address? : http://delphi-spring-framework.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/